# pyspark: Casting timestamp to "timestamp_ltz" when pulling from snowflake

Tags: python, pyspark, timestamp, timezone, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

So our snowflake uses TIMESTAMP_LTZ, timestamp is America/New_york with no offset information. and I am trying to pull data from snowflake using pyspark.

There are two approaches to do this:

1. set pyspark session to "America/New_York", alter snowflake session timezone to "America/New_york", and cast the timestamp to "TIMESTAMP_LTZ":

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/New_York")

start = '2023-05-01 14:00:00'
end = '2023-05-01 15:00:00'

sql_query = \
    """
select id, created_at::timestamp_ltz from db.table where created_at > '{start}'and created_at < '{end}' limit 1
    """

df = (spark.read
    .format("snowflake")
    .option("query", sql_query.format(start=start, end=end))
    .option("sfUrl", host_url)
    .option("sfUser", username)
    .option("sfPassword", password)
    .option("sfDatabase", database_name)
    .option("sfWarehouse", warehouse_name)
    .option('partition_size_in_mb', 80)
    .option('use_cached_result', 'true')
    .option('use_copy_unload', 'false')
    .option('parallelism', '40')
    .option("sfCompress","on")
    .option("sfTimezone", "America/New_York")
    .load()
)
```

This will gives me the right data with the right timestamp

2. The second approach is to use pyspark filter function, however, I am not sure how I can cast timestamp to "TIMESTAMP_LTZ", it gives me an error of "DataType timestamp_ltz is not supported."

```
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.session.timeZone", "America/New_York")

start = '2023-05-01 14:00:00'
end = '2023-05-01 15:00:00'

df = (spark.read
  .format("snowflake")
  .option("sfTimezone", "America/New_York")
  .option("dbtable", table_name)
  .option("sfUrl", host_url)
  .option("sfUser", username)
  .option("sfPassword", password)
  .option("sfDatabase", database_name)
  .option("sfSchema", schema_name)
  .option("sfWarehouse", warehouse_name)
  .load()
)

df = df.selectExpr("ID", "CREATED_AT::TIMESTAMP_LTZ as CREATED_AT").limit(1)
df = df.filter(df.CREATED_AT.between(start,end))
```

If I don't cast the timestamp to "TIMESTAMP_LTZ", it will treat the timestamp as UTC and shift it when I use toPandas() function or save as a delta table, resulting in an incorrect timestamp.

Some might also suggest to set both the spark session and snowflake session as UTC. This also grabs the right data, but it adds a "+0000" suffix when I save to delta table which also makes the timestamp invalid. If I can save to delta table without timezone I guess it could work too but I am not sure how to do it.